# Dropdown to read in and sort users with PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a project where I need to read in users (am using MySQL) and be able to sort 1. Men/Women 2. Salary (eg. 30k+, 50k+, 100k+...)

I've tried setting up a select dropdown but for some reason it's showing only the men, even if I select women.

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
      <select name="Gender">
         <option value=''>Select Gender</option>
         <option value="Men">Men</option>
         <option value="Women">Women</option>
      </select>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] = "Men"){
        $selected_val = $_POST['Gender'];  
        echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;
        $conn = create_Conn();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE kon='Man'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if (isset($_SESSION['anvnamn'])) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              //Prints user data
            }
        }
        else {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             //Prints user data but emails
            }
        }

}
elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] = "Women"){
        $selected_val = $_POST['Gender'];  
        echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;
        $conn = create_Conn();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE kon='Woman'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if (isset($_SESSION['anvnamn'])) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               //Prints user data
            }
        }
        else {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               //Prints user data but emails
            }
        }

}
else {
        print("-");
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['submit'] = "Men"` you are assigning the value `"Men"` to `$_POST['submit']`. The same goes for `"Women"`. You meant using `==`

Comment: Single equals sign is an assignment. Double or even triple equals is a comparison. If you find yourself making this typo often change the order of operands i.e. `"Men" === $_POST['submit']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've assigned the values in the `if`s instead of comparing against them. Also, you've used the wrong input to compare against. `$_POST['submit']` will always contain the value `Get Selected Values`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['Gender'] === "Men") {
    $selected_val = $_POST['Gender'];
    echo "You have selected :" . $selected_val;
    $conn   = create_Conn();
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE kon='Man'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (isset($_SESSION['anvnamn'])) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Prints user data
        }
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Prints user data but emails
        }
    }

} elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['Gender'] === "Women") {
    $selected_val = $_POST['Gender'];
    echo "You have selected :" . $selected_val;
    $conn   = create_Conn();
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE kon='Woman'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (isset($_SESSION['anvnamn'])) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Prints user data
        }
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Prints user data but emails
        }
    }

} else {
    print("-");
}
```

---

Here's the code a little more simplified and less redundant. And under the assumption that you're using PHPs [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'post') {
    $gender = $_POST['Gender'] ?? null; // your old $selected_val variable

    if (!$gender) {
        // do something to abort the execution and display an error message.
        // for now, we're killing it.
        print '-';
        exit;
    }

    /** @var PDO $dbConnection */
    $dbConnection = create_Conn();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE kon = :gender';
    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam('gender', $gender);
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $user) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['anvnamn'])) {
            // Prints user data
        } else {
            // Prints user data but emails
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still pretty new to this whole thing.
Can I do the same thing but with salary? For example in the sql i do "SELECT * FROM users WHERE salary>#####"?

Comment: Sure. Why not? I don't see any big difference besides an input field and a slightly different query for that.

Comment: Cool, I wasnt sure if > < worked in SQL or if I would have had to use some other method for it

Comment: No, normal comparison works fine in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: I've also added a more simplified and less redundant example of your code. It's untested but might help you.

Comment: The only trouble with injecting the value from the form is a disparity between the form and the data - the form uses Women/Men and the database uses Woman/Man. However, I presume that can be fixed in one of those places.

Comment: Yes, it's also not getting validated at all.

Answer (score 2):

As **Dan** has provided a grand answer prior to mine, this is now just a tack on for something to review.

If you look at your form you have two elements.
On Submission, your script will see..

1. Gender - $_POST['Gender'] will either be '', 'Men', or 'Women'
2. Submit - $_POST['submit'] will either be null or the value "Get Selected Values". 
   It can only be null if the php file is called by something else.

You can see this by using the command print_r($_POST) in your code just before your first if(). This allows you to test and check what is actually being posted during debugging.

So to see if the form is posted you could blanket your code with an outer check for the submit and then check the state of Gender.

The following has the corrections to your IF()s and some suggestions to also tidy up the code a little bit.

```
<?php

// Process the form data using Ternary operators
// Test ? True Condition : False Condition
$form_submitted = isset($_POST['submit'])? $_POST['submit']:FALSE;
$gender = isset($_POST['Gender'])? $_POST['Gender']:FALSE;

if($form_submitted){
  if($gender == 'Men') {
    // Stuff here
  }
  else if($gender == 'Women') {
    // Stuff here
  }
  else {
    print("-");
  }
} else {
  // Optional: Case where the form wasn't submitted if other code is present.
}
```

You could also consider using the switch / case structure. I'll leave that to you to look up.